# How can I force rustqlite to be built as statically linked when using sqlcipher?

Tags: rust, ld, static-linking, rust-cargo

I'm using `rustqlite` and am trying to configure it to use `sqlcipher` via a Cargo feature. In the usual case, `rustqlite` has a `bundled` feature to include the `sqlite` source. When changing to `sqlcipher`, the source isn't bundled anymore.

Locally I was able to install `sqlcipher` and compile my project (installed via `brew install sqlcipher` on Mac).

The resulting binary dynamically links to the local `sqlcipher` installation so I can no longer distribute the binary to customers

How I can I embed the library `libsqlcipher.0.dylib` into the binary? Customers can't be expected to install `sqlcipher` on their own.

For reference, looking at the linked libraries for a dummy project:

```
/tmp/try-sqlite/cipher$ otool -L target/release/cipher
target/release/cipher:
    /usr/local/opt/sqlcipher/lib/libsqlcipher.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

My project is simple:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "cipher"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]


[dependencies.rusqlite]
version = "0.24.2"
features = ["sqlcipher"]
```

**main.rs**

```rust
use rusqlite::{params, Connection, Result, NO_PARAMS};
use std::thread::sleep;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    data: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let conn = Connection::open("/tmp/enc2.db")?;

    conn.execute("PRAGMA KEY='passphrase'", NO_PARAMS);
    conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
                  id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                  name            TEXT NOT NULL,
                  data            BLOB
                  )",
        NO_PARAMS,
    )?;
    let me = Person {
        id: 0,
        name: "Steven".to_string(),
        data: None,
    };
    conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO person (name, data) VALUES (?1, ?2)",
        params![me.name, me.data],
    )?;

    let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT id, name, data FROM person")?;
    let person_iter = stmt.query_map(NO_PARAMS, |row| {
        Ok(Person {
            id: row.get(0)?,
            name: row.get(1)?,
            data: row.get(2)?,
        })
    })?;

    for person in person_iter {
        println!("Found person {:?}", person.unwrap());
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

**EDIT**

I have a partial solution to static linking (not tested robustly yet) by exporting
`SQLCIPHER_STATIC=1`

```
otool -L /private/tmp/try-sqlite/cypher/target/debug/cypher
/private/tmp/try-sqlite/cypher/target/debug/cypher:
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Open issues

1. how to auto-export this environment variable (through `toml` config / `build.rs` - still working on that)
2. developer ergonomics - how to ensure that `sqlcipher` is installed on a dev machine (through `build.rs` / `toml dev` etc. config)
3. ensure that CI will run with SQLCIPHER_STATIC=1 (and have it installed)

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: it's not a solution - it's a start

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is currently [not possible](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/issues/765) with the version published on `crates.io`.

But there is an open [Pull Request](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/pull/860) that you can probably use for that.

First clone the [working branch](https://github.com/dubiousjim/rusqlite/tree/push2) locally and then use it as a [patch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/cargo-and-crates-io/replacing-dependencies-with-patch.html) in your `Cargo.toml` like that:

```
[dependencies]
rusqlite = { version = "0.24.2", features = ["bundled-sqlcipher"] }

[patch.crates-io]
rusqlite = { path = "../path/to/your_patch" }
```

Note that I did not test this and because the feature only exists in the patch it might be that you need to include the feature branch like that:

```
[dependencies]
rusqlite = { path = "../path/to/your_patch", features = ["bundled-sqlcipher"] }
```

**A word of Warning:** As stated in the PR it is not clear if zetetic (the vendor of `sqlcipher`) is fine with that, so you should be cautious when you use this (especially in a commercial product).

### Edit

This [Issue / Comment](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/issues/558#issuecomment-518731705) is also relevant.